# Filtering rows in bigquery based on user parameters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a following sample table:

| Info | County | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| info1 | Sonoma | California |
| info2 | Fresno | California |
| info3 | Lake | California |
| info5 | Lake | Florida |

I need to select say, Sonoma county from California and Lake county from Florida. I need to pass the needed counties and the needed states as list parameters so that they could be given as arguments to a script.

```
SELECT
    ST_UNION_AGG(Info) as counties_info
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE
    County IN UNNEST(@counties) AND
    State IN UNNEST(@states)
```

This query will also give me the Lake county in California, how do I modify the script while still using the needed list parameters [`@counties` and `@states`]?

**NOTE**: I cannot check for individual states as the `@states` parameters can have any state in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using structs for the parameters:

```
SELECT ST_UNION_AGG(t.Info) as counties_info
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(@county_states) cs
              WHERE cs.county = t.county AND cs.state = t.state
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
select ...
from `project.dataset.table`
where (State, County) in unnest(@state_county_pairs)
```

above assumes that your `@state_county_pairs` parameter is an array of sate, county pairs - like in below script

```
declare state_county_pairs array<struct<State string, Country string>> ;
set state_county_pairs =  [
  struct('California' as State, 'Sonoma' as County),
  struct('Florida', 'Lake')
];

select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where (State, County) in unnest(state_county_pairs)
```

with output (if applied to sample data in your question)

[image]

Obviously, then you can do whatever aggregation or other logic you need
I am not reusing your `ST_UNION_AGG(Info) as counties_info` because it makes no sense having in mind presented values of `Info` field, but I hope this was just for simplification purposes, so I am using just `select *` here

Meantime, below is example using real data with geo data type which applicable to use with ST_ functions

```
select st_union_agg(county_geom) as counties_geo
from `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_county_area`
join `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_states_area`
using (state_fips_code)
where (state_name, county_name) in unnest(@var_state_county_pairs)
```

with output that combines those two counties geo info and is visualized as below

[image]